# What's a "right old roarer" in British English?

Tags: meaning, british-english, slang

I was reading an Amazon review just now, and came across someone (Tchaikovsky) being described as a *right old roarer*.  I'm guessing this is familiar slang to Brits, but I'm not getting good search results, and it's a bit difficult to infer the meaning through context.  What does it mean?  Is it common use?

Comment: That's archaic now, definitely not in common use.

Answer (score 6):

If this is the [Amazon context](http://www.amazon.co.uk/review/RMNWJ35H2BW2Y) you refer to,

> The more Tchaikovsky's reputation grew
>   as a composer, the more anxious he
>   became to avoid public disclosure as a
>   homosexual. He was a right old roarer
>   apparently, specialising in boys in
>   their early to mid teens.

it seems quite well-fitting with the [slang definition](http://www.slang-dictionary.com/definition/roarer.html) of roarer

```
a male homosexual, especially one who is actually or supposedly flagrant.
```

I've not come across this word myself before, so not sure how common this is in BrE.

Without the full context, I thought roarer meant "someone who communicates vocally in a very loud voice"

Comment: Not very common at all (as in, that's the first time I've heard it).  Then again, many slang terms appear and disappear like mayflies.

Comment: On an unrelated note, it's getting difficult to identify words with slang meanings in BrE, have only learnt last week "grooming" means something different and perverse too.

Answer (score 1):

From Auden's *As I Walked Out One Evening*:

> …
>   And the crack in the tea-cup opens
>   A lane to the land of the dead.
>
> Where the beggars raffle the banknotes
>   And the Giant is enchanting to Jack,
>   And the Lily-white Boy is a Roarer,
>   And Jill goes down on her back
>   …

Comment: Welcome to EL&U! Good info.

Answer (score -1):

I think "old roarer" is much used in British slang by straight men when referring to homosexuals.